# React-Bootstrap Form Control Input Space Before Text Is Gone in Firefox

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

In my Form Input that has a classname of "Form-Control", things work properly in Chrome like this:

[image: Input in Chrome]

However, the white space that I believe is coming from padding, which doesn't work on my Firefox, disappears like this:

[image: Input in Firefox]

Is there any way for me to use CSS to work it out so that the white space shows up in Firefox? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a [Bootstrap bug](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/) that doesn't support Firefox, or something like that.
But try to add this code:

```
.form-control {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but nothing was changed.